# Creating a Plan in Planner

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a plan in Planner. The endpoint I call is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/planner/plans
```

In return I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "You do not have the required permissions to access this item, or the item may not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2654b7da-4ee4-47b8-83f8-e9514088c095",
      "date": "2018-10-01T10:57:34"
    }
  }
}
```

My permissions and scopes are:

```
SCOPES = ['User.Read', 'Group.ReadWrite.All']
```

I gave Admin Consent for these permissions.

As a payload I send:

```
{
  "title": "test",
  "owner": "<myID>"
}
```

Where `<myID>` is the ID of the account requested per `/me`

Still it does not work - what did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `owner` property should be a Group's `id`, not the User's `id`. Users can only have one individual "plan". Since this already exists, you cannot create a new one.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_plans):

> In the request body, supply a JSON representation of [plannerPlan object](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannerplan). The `owner` property must be set to an `id` of a [group object](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group).